# Wordpress Menu Disappears when $query->query_vars['meta_key'] is set

Tags: wordpress, sorting, metadata

I've set some meta variables on my WP posts. I want to be able to sort by these variables, and everything is working great except when I sort by either "views" or "likes". When I sort by either of those two fields, WP doesn't generate my nav (wp_nav_menu).

I've tried "resetting" the $wp_query variable surrounding my wp_nav_menu call:

```
$old_query = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'any') ); 
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); 
$wp_query = $old_query;
```

But that does not solve it. The only thing that does work is commenting out the line starting $query->query_vars['meta_key'], but obviously that negates the sort as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Before a query is run, modify the sort order
function jh_popularity_sort_query($query) {
  $sort = $_GET['sort']; 
  if ($sort == "title") {
    $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'title';
    $query->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
  } else if ($sort == "date") {
    $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'date';
  } else if ($sort == "views") {
    $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'jh_page_views';
    $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
  } else if ($sort == "likes") {
    $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'jh_page_likes';
    $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
  }

  return $query;
} add_action('pre_get_posts', 'jh_popularity_sort_query');
```

Comment: You might have a better luck to find the correct answer over here sir: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even realize that existed.

Comment: Moved this to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52402/wordpress-menu-disappears-when-query-query-varsmeta-key-is-set but I can't self-answer and close this yet because I don't yet have the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this and moving to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ per allaire's suggestion.

For anyone who has this problem, helenhousandi had the solution right on. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52408/16201